# R error on matrix multiplication: non-conformable arguments

Tags: r, loops

I have an R loop that has been giving me error. Here are the dimensions of the matrices..

```
      > dim(A)
     [1] 2 2
     > dim(backward)
     [1] 6848    2
```

I am trying to run this loop and get the following error:

```
      for (i in t:1){
      backward[i,]=A%*%t(backward[i,])}
      Error in A %*% t(backward[i, ]) : non-conformable arguments
```

Where t equals 6848. Thanks for your time.

EDIT with bgoldst code:

```
           > A
          [,1] [,2]
        [1,]  0.8  0.2
        [2,]  0.2  0.8
        > backward <- matrix(1:(t*2),t,2);
        >   dim(backward)
       [1] 6848    2
       > for (i in t:1) backward[i,] <- A%*%t(backward[i,,drop=F]);
       Error in A %*% t(backward[i, , drop = F]) : non-conformable arguments
```

Comment: `dim(t(backward[i,]))` will tell you where the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that your expectation of

```
backward[i,]
```

is that it will return a 1x2 matrix, which you would be able to use as the operand of a matrix multiplication. This is incorrect. In R, when you specify a single index within a dimension of a matrix, then by default, R will "drop" that dimension. In the case of the above piece of code, the row dimension is dropped, and you end up with a vector, whose contents are taken from all columns along the indexed row. A vector is not a valid operand to a matrix multiplication.

You can solve this problem by providing the `drop` argument to the `[` operation:

```
A <- matrix(1:(2*2),2,2);
backward <- matrix(1:(6848*2),6848,2);
t <- nrow(backward); for (i in t:1) backward[i,] <- A%*%t(backward[i,,drop=F]); ## no error
```

Here's a demo of the effect of `drop=F`:

```
backward[1,]
## [1] 20548 27398
backward[1,,drop=F]
##       [,1]  [,2]
## [1,] 20548 27398
```

See [`` ?`[` ``](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) for more info.

---

Here's a solution that doesn't depend on the `drop=F` argument:

```
for (i in t:1) backward[i,] <- A%*%t(matrix(backward[i,],1));
```

Comment: Hi bgoldst,  I tried your code and for some reason I still get an error. Please refer to original post edit

Comment: @ali.hash, hmm, that's strange. I don't get that error. Can you give me your `R.version.string`? Mine is `[1] "R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)"`.

Comment: > R.version.string
[1] "R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)"

Comment: That's a few years old; I'd suggest upgrading to a recent version of R, and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Ya thats weird. I am running R Studio for mac and this is the latest update thats out: > R.version.string
[1] "R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)"